# Image Uploading using angular and asp.net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, angularjs

am trying to get the image from the PC and upload it into the DB 
as `like "/Images/aaa.jpg"` am new to angular. Here am tried one example. Its not worked For me. i have stucked almost 3 days to solve this. but i couldn't found any tutorials for my requirement. when i debug the id, and descriptions are passing correctly, but For the path its remaining always null. and i know i need to set path to where the picture will save. but i dont know how to do that, please  can anyone help me to solve this issue.

I tried this one to upload image.

```
$scope.uploadFile = function(files) {
    var fd = new FormData();
    //Take the first selected file
    fd.append("file", files[0]);

    $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
        withCredentials: true,
        headers: {'Content-Type': undefined },
        transformRequest: angular.identity
    }).success(ya).error( noo );

};
```

There is a add button if user hit add button details want to be save. for this i used this one.

```
 $scope.AddImage = function () {


        var dataObj = {
            Id: $scope.Id,
            Description: $scope.Description,
            Path: $scope.Path,
            Location: $scope.Location,

        };. 

var request = $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: urls.api + 'Images/AddImage',
            //data: JSON.stringify(dataObj)
            data: dataObj

        }).success(function (data, status) {
            alert('saved succesfully');
        })
    .error(function (error) {
        $scope.status = 'Unable to load ImageDetails : ' + error.message;
        console.log($scope.status);
    });
    }
```

this is my asp.net services.

```
 public async Task<int?> Addimg (Addimg dto)
        {
            try
            {
                var d = _dbContext.img
            .FirstOrDefault();


                d.img_Path = dto.Path.ToString();
                d.img_Description = dto.Description;
                d.img_Location = dto.Location;


                //mark entry as modifed
                _dbContext.Entry(d).State = EntityState.Modified;
                await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
                return d.img_Id;
            }
```

this my asp.net controller

```
 [HttpPost]
 [Route("AddImage")]
 public async Task<IHttpActionResult> AddBanner(DisplayBannersDto dto)
 {
      if (!ModelState.IsValid)
           return BadRequest(ModelState);

      int? result = await _service.Addbanner(dto);
       return Ok();

  }
 }
```

Please provide if there is any alternative codes.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're uploading a file and doing nothing with it...

You could add something like the following property to your DisplayBannersDto model:

```
public Stream InputStream { get; set; }
```

You can then either save the file to disk from the stream, or in the database as a blob.

Comment: The angular code you have looks okay.
In your controller you should be able to gain access to the file with something like:

var file = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0];
var filestream = file.InputStream;
var filename = file.FileName;

Obviously you'd want to add some exception handling / null checks etc. to make it more robust, but essentially that's it!